# Why the foreach classlist.remove iteration is not working?

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, iteration

I have a problem with this code in my slider.
I need to remove a class from all array elements. The length of the array may vary.
this code works:

```
updateGallery() {
    this.carouselArray.forEach((el, i ) => {
        el.classList.remove('gallery-item-1');
        el.classList.remove('gallery-item-2');
        el.classList.remove('gallery-item-3');
        el.classList.remove('gallery-item-4');
        el.classList.remove('gallery-item-5');
    });
    let carouselSliceLength = this.carouselArray.slice().length;
    this.carouselArray.slice(0, carouselSliceLength).forEach((el, i) => {
        el.classList.add(`gallery-item-${i+1}`);
    });
}
```

but this code doesn't work:

```
updateGallery() {
    this.carouselArray.forEach((el, i ) => {
       el.classList.remove(`gallery-item-${i+1}`);
    });
    let carouselSliceLength = this.carouselArray.slice().length;
    this.carouselArray.slice(0, carouselSliceLength).forEach((el, i) => {
        el.classList.add(`gallery-item-${i+1}`);
    });
}
```

Why?

Comment: How about this `"gallery-item-" + $i`?

Comment: `i` is the position of the element in the array. It's definitely not numbers 1-5. And even then you only have a single call to `.remove()` not five.

Comment: @MarkusSafar syntax error?

Comment: Useful links: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173) and [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Why don't you try to print `i` (using console.log) and see what it shows?

Comment: Why are you calling `slice` so much?

Comment: `this.carouselArray.slice().length` is going to be exactly the same a `this.carouselArray.length`, and it makes a needless new array that is immediately thrown away.

Comment: The two pieces of code are certainly not equivalent. In the first you perform 5 removals in each iteration, and in the second you only perform one per iteration. Without seeing the HTML, it is not clear what needs to happen.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the HTML, JavaScript etc. to reproduce your problem IN your question.

Comment: @VLAZ: Thank you for your comment but please enlighten me. Beside the fact that I misunderstood the question, why would this be a syntactical error? As far as I see it we have a string, an integer and an add operator. To my understanding of the javascript language the integer will be casted to a string which leaves us with a string concatenation, right?

Comment: @MarkusSafar the identifier `$i` does not exist.

Comment: @VLAZ It seems I should sleep a little bit more :D Thank's for the hint ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are doing different things. In the first implementation, you are removing five different elements for an element in the array (five calls of the `remove` function).

Whereas the second implementation calls only one `remove` for each element. So for the first element, it will remove `gallery-item-1` for the second `gallery-item-2` and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, devs.
I made loops in a loop and corrected the code.
This code works. Deletes classes and adds new ones. The 3d slider works.

```
updateGallery() {
    const carouselLength = this.carouselArray.length
    this.carouselArray.forEach(el => {
        for (let i=1; i<=carouselLength; i++) {
            el.classList.remove(`gallery-item-${i}`);
        }
    });
    this.carouselArray.slice(0, carouselLength).forEach((el, i) => {
        el.classList.add(`gallery-item-${i+1}`);
    });
}
```

Thanks!